# Extend MouseArea beyond component

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a Rectangle with width 1 (a line), which should be draggable:

```
Rectangle {
    id: recMark
    border.width: 0
    width: 1
    height: parent.height
    y: 0
    color: "red"
    opacity: 0.3
    visible: true
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: recMark
        drag.axis: Drag.XAxis

    }
}
```

Is it possible to extend the mouse area beyond the rectangle, e.g. 3 pixels around it? Obviously it would be hard to hit the right pixel with the mouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add negative `margins` to the `MouseArea`:

```
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: -3
    // ...
}
```